# SQL complex unions

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, cross-apply

This is a little tricky to describe, but hopefully there is a solution.

I have a UDF which takes an ID and returns a table. Is there a way I can do a `SELECT` for these IDs and perform a `UNION` of the UDF results? For example;

> ***To get the IDs;***
>
> SELECT [ID]
>   FROM [TableOfIDs]
>
> ***To get the object properties from an ID;***
>
> SELECT *
>   FROM GetObjectProperties(@ID)

But how do I combine the two? That is, to do a union of the UDF results from a query for the IDs?

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: The syntax depends on the RDBMS you're using. You need to tag your question with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx):

```
SELECT TT.* 
FROM [TableOfIDs] AS T CROSS APPLY GetObjectProperties(T.ID) AS TT;
```